# Despite running without problems, my battery indicator says "(not present)" still - what can I do about this?

Tags: 11.10, battery, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the correct battery status?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100325/how-to-get-the-correct-battery-status)

Every time I restart me computer I have to go into system settings to turn the brightness on my screen back up to full and the computer thinks there's no battery - there definitely is! Apart from that I've had no performance issues, it's just dang annoying and I don't understand it, because it was working fine last night, the indicator-battery was displaying correctly, but when I turned on my computer this morning (like nine hours later), it was broken.

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0` or `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT1` spit out? In terminal run:
`cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0` or `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1` Mine is practically dead but still seen by the system although the applet sometimes doesn't, which mean the applet has a bug.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!