# acer travelmate 8371 doesn't charge battery since ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, battery

Since the Update to 12.04 my battery won't charge - it says it's charged to 51% - when i disconnect the powercable thee is no energy supply at all.

How can i figure out if it's a hardware problem or the new ubuntuversion? And how can i fix it?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100325/how-to-get-the-correct-battery-status)

Comment: I meant to also say updating the BIOS may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting to a LiveCD or LiveUSB for the version you used to have installed.  This way, you will be running on a completely independent instance of the operating system, so if the problem persists you know it is your hardware and not the software.  You could also try a LiveCD for Ubuntu 12.04 to see if it is a configuration issue.