# Ubuntu 12.04 laptop battery isn't charging?

Tags: laptop, suspend, battery

My HP EliteBook charged perfectly when Windows 7 was installed. 8560p. I wiped the drive, installed 12.04. For a little while, I could suspend the laptop, and it would charge when the lid was closed. At some point in the last week, after some update, the battery never charges and it doesn't seem like the laptop suspends or hibernates properly any more.

Comment: FWIW Acer Aspire One Pro does the same. I just yesterday upgraded to 12.04, and it does not charge any more when Ubuntu is running. It did with 11.10. Hibernate seems to crash always with kernel oops (but it did so occasionally also with 11.10).

Comment: Updating the BIOS may help, take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100325/how-to-get-the-correct-battery-status)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been abandoned.