# Ubuntu 14.04 Battery Icon has fixed value after booting till the next reboot [UPDATED]

Tags: 14.04, unity, power-management, battery

I have a dual-booted Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Win8.1 on a Dell inspiron 14 series 5000 machine. It tire me with alot of bugs starting with wireless instability and showing new ones with each update I guess.

Recently, when I start my computer, the battery shows a correct percentage whether power is plugged in or not but it never changes. The value is fixed until the power is drained completely, only then I know I should plug the power in. 
When running :

```
 upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

I get:

```
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 02:00:00 EET (1442252072 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

and when running:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
```

I get:

```
     native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                DELL R0JM64B4
  serial:               0994
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 14 Sep 2015 19:47:30 EET (84 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              16.7292 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         39.6468 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45.144 Wh
    energy-rate:         11.1888 W
    voltage:             10.65 V
    time to empty:       1.5 hours
    percentage:          42%
    capacity:            87.823%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-good-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1442252850  42.000  discharging
```

The `time to empty` is the real time not the displayed one in battery icon.

[UPDATE]
Running:

```
acpi -b
```

Gets me:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 15%, 00:32:53 remaining
```

Comment: What make and model of laptop are you using? You probably need to change the ACPI set up. Relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100325/how-to-get-the-correct-battery-status

Comment: @Wilf , I didn't always have this problem as that post's author. and running `acpi -b` gets me different result. **updated the post with lap model & results of that cmd**

Comment: Does this problem persist if you boot from a Live CD

Comment: @Daniel No it doesn't.

Comment: Then you likely need to reinstall some package.

Comment: @Daniel How do I know what packages I need to reinstall?

Comment: Try running this command:  `sudo apt-get install acpid acpi-support`

Comment: A reboot may or may not be required

Comment: @Daniel
`acpi-support is already the newest version.
acpid is already the newest version.
acpid set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

Comment: Hmmm, how about `sudo apt-get install toshset`

Comment: Also, you might want to read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportMachinesLaptopsDell

Comment: Find your model and see if there are known issues and solutions

Comment: Nope. tried what you suggested. I'm afraid it's a conky/compiz thing bcuz when I click on the battery icon, the details window shows correct info too just like the terminal.